# Array with Mysql result to JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

In PHP I am trying to turn an array with information from my database into JSON and then pass it to JavaScript. After a lot of googling I´ve come up with this solution but it wont work and I can´t figure out whats wrong. Heres the php code. (I have checked the results fromt the SQL query and it gives the result i need).

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM articles";
$result = $conn->query($query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

$articles = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
$articles[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($articles);
```

The echo outputs nothing and I can´t figure out why.
All help appreciated.

Comment: Where is the $blogPosts variable?

Comment: `var_dump($row)`, see what is in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this after the while loop but before the json_encode:

```
array_walk_recursive(
    $articles,
    function (&$entry) {
        $entry = utf8_encode($entry);
    }
);
```

Comment: this is what print_r($row) gives: Array ( [0] => 1 [id] => 1 [1] => Hello! [title] => Hello! [2] => Hi [text] => Hi) Array ( [0] => 2 [id] => 2 [1] => someText [title] => someText [2] => Text [text] => Text)

Comment: Hmmm. Are you sure your code is exactly as stated in your question. It looks like `$articles[]` is getting reset somewhere...

Comment: Yup im sure. Do you think there is something wrong with my php settings? Im using php version 5.5.3

Comment: Rather than echo the json_encode, replace that line with `print_r($articles);` instead. See what you get.

Comment: print_r($articles); gives me this: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [id] => 1 [1] => Hello! [title] => Hello! [2] => Hi [text] => Hi [3] ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 [id] => 2 [1] => someText [title] => someText [2] => Text [text] => Text ) )

Comment: Perfect, $articles contains what it should, so there is something wrong with json_encode. PHP 5.5.3 definitely has it, so I am not sure what the problem is. Try this to test `$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);`

Comment: Very odd. Turn on error reporting and try your original json_encode echo - `error_reporting(E_STRICT | E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);`

Comment: Still outputs nothing. Im using FireFox btw.

Comment: No worries. Might want to check the data in your database, there seems to be some weird characters in there. Don't forget to mark my answer as correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
echo json_encode($blogPosts);
```

with

```
echo json_encode($articles);
```

Comment: Check if your MySQL result returns any value(s) by putting `var_dump($row);` inside your while-loop

Comment: this is what var_dump($row); gives: array(10) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(12) "Hello" ["title"]=> string(12) "Hello" [2]=> string(10) "Hi" ["text"]=> string(10) "Hi" } array(10) { [0]=> string(1) "2" ["id"]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(6) "someText" ["title"]=> string(6) "someText" [2]=> string(4) "Text" ["text"]=> string(4) "Text"  }

Comment: Can you update your question and put in the complete php file you're  using? And do you have error_reporting on? (`error_reporting(-1);`)